# Is there any benefit of using null first in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some experienced programmers write comparisons with the value before the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309089/why-do-some-experienced-programmers-write-expressions-this-way)

I am just curious about this: in most frameworks/opensource projects I have studied, I often seen code like this...

```
<?php

if (null === self::$_instance) {
    self::$_instance = new self();
}
```

In particular this line...

```
if (null === self::$_instance) {
```

Why use `null` in the first argument of the `if` statement instead of the other way around?...

```
if (self::$_instance === null) {
```

I realize there is probably no performance increase or anything like that. Is this just a preference or is it some kind of coding standard I have overlooked?

Comment: Personally, I am inclined to say that they all should be `if( !self::$_instance )`

Comment: If this isn't a dup I'll eat my keyboard

Comment: That notation style is know as "yoda expressions" or "yoda conditions".

Comment: Glad you asked! I have always been curious, and I don't really like the null-first style. If there's a good reason for it though, maybe I'll adopt it.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: The OP is testing for exact equality to null, but your example would also match false, zero, and empty string.

Comment: Putting expressions on the left and variables on the right side of a condition can help tremendeous in some cases. E.g. if you want to compare s/t with `==` but miss or delete an equal sign by accident, then an `if ($x = 1)` will just evaluate w/o notice, whereas `if (1 = $x)` would throw an error message.

Comment: @Bill This looks like a Singleton pattern. If it is, then $_instance *better* not be `0`, `FALSE`, or `''`. If it isn't, then the authors of the framework are a little goofy.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: *Most* authors of frameworks are a little goofy.  ;-)

Comment: @Bill as someone authoring a framework, I represent that remark!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do some experienced programmers write comparisons with the value before the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309089/why-do-some-experienced-programmers-write-comparisons-with-the-value-before-the)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It prevents you from accidentally assigning the value to a variable, especially when only using loose type comparison (`==`):

```
if (self::$_instance = NULL) { … } // WHOOPS!, self::$_instance is now NULL
```

This style of conditions is often called [yoda conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307). Performance wise there is no difference, both statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

This is mainly to prevent accidental assignment:

```
if (self::$_instance = null) ... //oops!
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no significant performance difference.  The usual benefit of writing expressions in this way is defensive programming.  We want to avoid accidentally using an assignment instead of equality comparison:

```
if (self::$_instance = null) { ...
```

Woops!

Comment: Wow, three virtually identical simultaneous answers.  Somebody is owed a Coke.

Answer (score 4):

It's to help you get your code right.

If you do this, your code will work, but the effect will be a long way from what you want:

```
if (self::$instance = null) {
```

The conditional will always fail (because the `=` operator returns the value set, and it is falsy) but `self::$instance` will now be set to `null`.  This isn't what you want.

If you do this:

```
if (null = self::$instance) {
```

your code will fail to work, because you can't use `null` (or any literal such as a string or an integer) on the left-hand-side of an assignment. Only variables can be the left-hand-side of the `=` operator.

So if you mistype the `==` as `=`, you get a parse error and your code completely doesn't work. This is preferable to a mystifying and hard-to-track-down bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's not particular to `null` - I've seen many coders prefer to write their expressions this way round:

```
if(8 == 4 * 2) {
```

It's just a preference which some people think is clearer.