# PHP why (null === $variable) and not ($variable === null) in comparison?

Tags: php

When reading `Symfony2` code I came across this comparaison many times

```
if (null === $variable ) { ... }
```

I use

`if ($variable === null ){ ... }`

because I see it more readable.

Is there a wisdom behind using the first notation ?

Comment: This question pops up from time to time, the older Q&A material we have on site is normally giving better directions as the quickly types answers nowadays: [Why does one often see “null != variable” instead of “variable != null” in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/271561/367456) (Nov 2008) - [Why do some experienced programmers write expressions this way? \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3309089/367456) (Jul 2010) - [Is there any benefit of using null first in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7261117/367456) (Aug 2011)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps prevent accidental assignments:

```
if ($foo = null) { ... }
```

would not cause a parse error, while will

```
if (null = $foo) { ... }
```

1st example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fff14c285a18a7972a3222ff5af08da825760c10
2nd example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/118d494c17381d8e129ba005465bf84d9b8819bd

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted.

Comment: I don't wonder why this was downvoted. -- linked demos are not working nor is given any info what they should stand for (and to allow me some personal taste: crappy code-pad site that is linked there)

Answer (score 6):

No compile/interpretting difference at all, it's pure code style.

It's also known as *Yoda Conditions*.

[image: Conditions, Yoda]

Answer (score 1):

Not only does it help prevent accidental assignments, but also avoids confusion when we do intentionally want to make an assignment when evaluating a condition.

```
if (null !== $article = $repository->findOneById($request->query->get('id'))) {
    $title = $article->getTitle();

    //....
}
```